# QueryDSL: JPA example for ConstructorExpression and CaseBuilder in QueryDSL 2.9.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, groovy, querydsl

```
public class ProductDTO {
   public ProductDTO(final String name, final Boolean isBrandNew) { ... }
}

QProduct product = QProduct.product

Expression<Boolean> isBrandNew = new CaseBuilder()
  .when(product.creaDate.eq(product.modDate)).then(Boolean.TRUE)
  .otherwise(Boolean.FALSE)
  .as("brandNewProduct")

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery (this.em);
query.from(product)
     .where(product.name.eq("blah"))
     .listDistinct(ConstructorExpression.create(ProductDTO
     , product.name
     , isBrandNew))
```

---

What is the correct setup for the CaseBuilder that would include the "brandNewProduct" column in the final select statement of my query?

Right now, all I get from hibernate is following exception

```
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectExpression
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CaseNode.getFirstThenNode(CaseNode.java:43)
```

Answer (score 3):

For future references...

Someone has already posted a similar problem [here](http://www.rqna.net/qna/pntypn-is-it-possible-to-use-querydsl-casebuilder-when-checking-for-null-value-in-a-left-join.html) and [here](https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/185).
According to Timo, there is a bug or let's say a limitation imposed by hibernate:

> Best Answer
>   Answered by Timo Westkämper on 2013-02-22T01:55:04-05:00
>   It is syntactically possible, but currently unsupported by Hibernate. Here is a related ticket https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/185

So, the solution posted by nithril actually works for me:

> query().from(cat).list(cat.name.when("Bob").then(Expressions.numberTemplate(Long, "1")).otherwise(Expressions.numberTemplate(Long, "2")));

and I ended up using:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery (this.em);
  query.from(product)
 .where(product.name.eq("blah"))
 .listDistinct(ConstructorExpression.create(ProductDTO
 , product.name
 , product.modDate.when(product.creaDate)
                  .then(Expressions.booleanTemplate("true"))
                  .otherwise(Expressions.booleanTemplate("false"))
```

))

Hope this helps in case someone else has the same problem.